# Memory & Computation Efficient Creation of Array with Repeated Elements

Tags: julia

I am trying to find an efficient way to create a new array by repeating each element of an old array a different, specified number of times.  I have come up with something that works, using array comprehensions, but it is not very efficient, either in memory or in computation:

```
LENGTH = 1e6
A = collect(1:LENGTH) ## arbitrary values that will be repeated specified numbers of times
NumRepeats = [rand(20:100) for idx = 1:LENGTH]  ## arbitrary numbers of times to repeat each value in A
B = vcat([ [A[idx] for n = 1:NumRepeats[idx]] for idx = 1:length(A) ]...)
```

Ideally, what I would like would be a structure akin to the sparse matrix apparatus that Julia has but that would instead store data efficiently based on the indices where repeated values occur.  Barring that, I would at least like an efficient way to create a vector such as B in the example above.  I looked into the `repeat()` function, but as far as I can tell from the documentation and my experimentation with the function, it is just for repeating slices of an array the same number of times for each slice.  What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for run-length encoding. There's an RLEVectors.jl package here: https://github.com/phaverty/RLEVectors.jl. Not sure how usable it is. You could also make your own data type fairly easily.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that does it!  RLEVectors appears to still have somewhat limited functionality.  In particular, if I wanted to add an RLEVector to another vector, I first had to convert the other vector to an RLEVector.  Likewise I couldn't do any kind of matrix multiplication with the RLEVector.  Nevertheless, even given those considerations, If I just modify the code above to create an RLEVector and then use collect() to turn it into a regular vector, the time savings are considerable.

Comment: Also, it looks like there is a reverse_rle function in the Stats base that does this same thing, and a bit quicker than the procedure with creating and then collecting the RLEVector.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for trying RLEVectors.jl. Some features and optimizations had been languishing on master without a version bump. It can definitely be mixed with other vectors for element-wise arithmetic. I'll put the linear algebra operations on the feature request list. Any additional feature suggestions would be most welcome.
RLEVectors.jl has a `rep` function that works like R's and RLEVectors.inverse_ree is like StatsBase.inverse_rle, but it works on run ends rather than lengths.

Comment: @Pete, welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems you are the author of RLEVectors and would like to maintain questions about your product in here. So I'd say, that's great :-) Be patient, with increasing reputation you'll have more freedom in here.